# Limit Emails Per Hour Per IP

Tags: email, smtp, ip

Anyone knows a script or software for CentOS and Windows that can be installed onto dedicated servers with no control panel limiting emails per hour per IP or full block.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: why not do your own research or create your own script?

Comment: If you are dedicated server provider and you're selling dedicated servers but you wanna limit emails per hour won't that be possible? To protect your servers from spam

Answer (score 1):

You forget to mention what SMTP server you are using. If using Postfix you'll have some build-in features like http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_message_rate_limit to reduce the number of messages a client can send along with http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#anvil_rate_time_unit to specify a period of time to monitor.

As far as i know there are no scripts nor interfaces to manage these settings in Postfix.